# Wave aspect of light (diffraction)

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

Explain why you can hear from behind a wall but you cannot see around it although both light and sound have a wave nature !

Comment: Keep in mind the absorption of the intervening medium plays a role as well! Most walls don't absorb sound fully. On the other hand you can see much better through a window than you can hear through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can, just not very much - larger wave lengths diffract more, and sound waves have much much larger wavelengths than visible light (with $\lambda < 1\mu m$).

But radio waves, which are just like visible light with much larger $\lambda$ diffract all the time, you can receive radio signals even when you're not a straight line from the transmitter.

I suggest you read more about [Arago's/Poisson's spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arago_spot) to see an example of diffraction in visible light. You should also read about Young's experiment too.

Good luck!

Comment: Young's experiment shows only that light can diffract like waves,that's the purpose of it.It is not what i'am interested in now .I know it and i don't need it. But what i'am talking  about is  the way we recieve these waves and which is totaly  different, in addition to the main characteristics of these waves fine?

Comment: I don't get it - what is your question? Light waves do diffract, but very little in our daily life (that's why ray optics is a thing, it is true for $\lambda \to 0$, and that is the case most of the times (microns is very small comparable to our daily objects.

Comment: I mean that sound can diffract through openings of a door into the another room ,but the struggle is with light ,what kind of light cannot diffract ,is it the light of the lamp for example in the same room ?

Comment: The one used in young's exp is laser through a relatively small slit ,i'am not matching things together

Comment: Young didn't have lasers - only sunlight. He did use small slits to observe the diffraction because the wavelength of light is small, as said earlier. If you want large diffraction patterns you'll need large "spacial coherence length".

Comment: The wavelength of sound is too large so yhat it can diffract but the wave lenght of light is small so ot will not do diffract

Comment: If you ever pointed a laser to a place farther away than a couple of meters - you'll see it has a bigger spot than when it came out of the laser, proving light does diffract :)

Comment: It is fine know you focused on using lazers no it is sun light ya3ne , we need the main points know!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54845/discussion-between-zahraa-haj-hassan-and-ofek-gillon).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example you can see something behind a wall but not hear something. Put a mirror over the wall and you will see what is behind the wall due to light reflection. And futhermore if you are in a house the window will protect you from noise but let through the light from the mirror.

So as you can see the setup of the experiment determines the result.

Sound needs a medium to propagate. During propagation takes place the dissipation of the sound wave. To proof that dissipation is a natural phenomenon take a tube and let sound through it. Behind the tube you will hear the sound around the tube. But a deep frequency you'll hear all around and a high frequency sound is more directed straight. For sound the dissipation is more important (dominant) than reflection.

For light it is different. In gases there is a dissipation due to reflections on gas molecules and dust. The image from this dissipation is nearly perfect diffuse. Only if there are hot slices of air (in desert) one get a [mirage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage).

Not taking in account gases light is going only in straight lines (more exact along geodesic paths). To get bend the light has to touch (to be under the influence) of an edge or to switch from air to an other medium (to switch between different media). But the dispersion angle for light is due to observation very low.

The statement

> although both light and sound have a wave nature

leads to a simplification which doesn't takes in account the need in medium for sound and the propagation of light without any medium. Smashing this two phenomena in one, it is said that then smaller the wavelength than lower the dispersion. But this simplification in my eyes is misleading (but it holds since lights frequencies are much higher sound frequencies).